# Error on changing button's text color to default?

Tags: java, android

I have a button with set color code:

```
buttonClicked.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
```

Now when I finish my timer, the text of all buttons reset to something else, so I need that text to go back to default. I tried this but I get error (i placed a comment near the end of my code for that error):

```
final OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            private Button buttonClicked;
            private int brojacKlikova = 0;

            public void onClick(View v) {
                brojacKlikova++;
                if (brojacKlikova < 16) {

                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x003333));

                if (buttonClicked == null) {
                    // first button is clicked
                    buttonClicked = button;
                } else {
                    // second button is clicked
                    if (buttonClicked.getTag().equals(button.getTag())) {
                        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x66FF33));
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        counter = counter + 5;
                        score.setText("Poeni: " + counter);
                    } else {
                        buttonClicked.setEnabled(false);
                        buttonClicked.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                        buttonClicked.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFCC99));
                        button.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    }
                    buttonClicked = null;
                }
                }else{
                buttonClicked = null;
                buttonClicked.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); //<--- here I get error
                brojacKlikova = 0;
                brojacVremena.cancel();
                mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchTask,2200);
         }
            }
     };
```

How to reset my button's text color to default?

Here's logcat:

```
03-28 23:59:29.357: W/dalvikvm(27918): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at rs.androidaplikacije.spojnice.Spojnice$1.onClick(Spojnice.java:77)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2506)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
03-28 23:59:29.467: E/AndroidRuntime(27918):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 23:59:31.167: I/Process(27918): Sending signal. PID: 27918 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Posted in my first post.

Answer (score 2):

```
buttonClicked = null;
buttonClicked.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Problem is here. You are assigned button to **`NULL`** and then you call property on it. This always throw **`NPE`**. Solution is to remove first line and it should work.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that was a problem but I can't remove that line. If I do, my game does not do what it suppose to, it get's messed up. I need to null my button before everything gets started again. But just for the test sake I did what you said, my game gets a little messed up, but still my color is not set to default.

Comment: @nabuko you cant do it, you need to change game logic. obviously is not good.

Comment: @nabuko or create some "helping" button variable.